# iphone image to Ruby on Rails - bad content body, parse_multipart

Tags: iphone, sql-server, image, ruby-on-rails-3, upload

I am trying to upload an image from the iPhone to a Ruby on Rails (RoR) server and I am getting the following error:

```
!\ FAILSAFE /!\  Thu Nov 11 23:51:39 CET 2010
Status: 500 Internal Server Error
bad content body
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/utils.rb:319:in `parse_multipart'
```

The communication to the RoR site works fine when I leave out the line below where I set the value for the string with multipart/form-data.

iPhone code:

```
 NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"logo1" ofType:@"png"];
 NSData *imageData   = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];

 NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/user/iphone_results_to_website/",
     serverString ];
 NSMutableURLRequest *imageRequest = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
 [imageRequest setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];


 [imageRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
 NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------  14737809831466499882746641449"];
    // Works fine without this next line:
 [imageRequest setValue: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

 NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:[imageData length] + 512];
 [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 
 [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"logo1.png\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
 [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 [imageRequest setHTTPBody:body];

 theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:imageRequest 
         delegate:self];


 if(theConnection) {
  theConnectionData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
  // theData is an instance variable
 } else {
  // failed to make connection
 }
```

On the RoR side I have RMagick, ImageMagick and attachment_fu installed and I have setup a Photo model for attachment_fu as:

RoR Photo model:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base

 has_attachment :storage       => :file_system,
             :resize_to     => '640x480',
             :thumbnails    => { :thumb => '160x120', :tiny => '50>' },
             :max_size      => 5.megabytes,
             :content_type  => :image,
             :processor     => 'Rmagick'
  validates_as_attachment
  belongs_to :user

###########################################################################

def uploaded_picture=(picture_field)
self.name          = base_part_of(picture_field.original_fielname)
self.content_type  = picture_field.content_type.chomp
self.data          = picture_field.read

end  # uploaded_picture

###########################################################################

def base_part_of(file_name)

 File.basename(file_name).gsub(/[^\w._-]/, '')

end  # base_part_of

###########################################################################


end
```

Does anyone know what the problem could be?  Could the problem be in my Objective-C code or in the RoR side?

Comment: I am having the same issue uploading images to a Rails 2.3.5 webapp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was a bug in rack-1.0.1:

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-4892

Upgrading to the latest version of rack requires upgrading Rails to 2.3.9.

Nope I was wrong, spoke too soon.  I'm still seeing this error with Rails 2.3.9 and rack-1.1.0.

Edit:

I had to remove this line to get it to work:

```
 [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to follow up and say the former didn't exactly work for me, but i had a similar problem. The following example worked however. I wound up commenting out a similar line.

http://www.travisdunn.com/posting-multipart-file-uploads-on-the-iphone